# connecting two or more devices via wifi with through my app

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi

I want to have my app able to connect to other devices over the same wifi network and transfer some data,  that is `phone A` and `phone B` have my app installed and are on the same network. I am able to connect two devices currently with one acting as server and the other being client but this is with a static `IP` reference to the server device. In the open world this `IP` will change of course so my problem is how do I get  `phone A` to start up as a server device then have `phone B` see the server device on the network and connect to it. So the server device would accept this client connection and carry out the needed actions when the connection is made. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have A device listening on port number x, and the client version (device B) looking for that same port number x. This could be wrong.

Comment: I was thinking something similar if it was possible to grab to the port i intend to use. But i'm unaware as to how to do this, if this way is feasible, and thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for DNS.  If you don't have a DNS server available you could invent a discovery protocol in which machine A periodically multicasts the IP & port on which it is listening.

Machine B joins the multicast group.  Once machine B knows A's address and port it can open a socket using the code you already have.

Comment: Do you have any samples of creating such a broadcast?

Comment: I don't have a ready example, but this is the general approach used by systems like DDS (Data Distribution System), CORBA, etc.   In fact DDS might suit your needs although it's a bit heavy-weight compared to what you doing now.